# How can I getting for consistent week number from leap year or normal year

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using PostgreSQL version 9.4.18, PostGIS Version 2.2
I'm using this function, and I'm using WW because don't want ISO week numbers...just the week number starting from 1 January:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_woy(timestamp with time zone) RETURNS int LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE AS $$SELECT to_char($1, 'WW')::int$$;
```

When I run the following query, every 4 years, the week number changes it's a leap year. I'm trying to get consistent week numbers from year to year for a certain date. So, for instance, when I run

```
SELECT f_woy(('2007-06-24 14:19:46.502-07'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at 
time zone 'america/los_angeles')::date)
```

as woy for 2004, 2005, 2006, and 2007 I get:

```
woy integer
25
```

But when I run it as:

```
SELECT f_woy(('2008-06-24 14:19:46.502-07'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at 
time zone 'america/los_angeles')::date)
```

I get

```
woy integer
26
```

Is there a way I can ignore the leap years and keep everything consistent, so that all 06-24 would be week number 25. I saw some posts about determining whether it was a leap year or not, but I'm having a hard time integrating that logic so that I can apply it to all queries where I'm examining week numbers.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. All definitions of week numbers that I know (ISO or non-ISO, week starting on Sunday or Monday) cannot achieve that the same day of the year has the same week number. That has nothing to do with leap years. It also affects dates in January and February. It has to do with the fact that years start with different week days.

Comment: Jan 1-7...Week 1.  Jan 8-14...Week 2.  Jan 15-21...Week 3.  This is the consistency I was looking for.  I wanted to ignore Feb 29, which throws off the consistency. I don't care what weekday the year starts with.  Jan 1-7 is always Week 1.  Dec 25-31 is always week 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` expression to check this year is or isn't a *leap year*

1. This year is *leap year* return result minus 1.
2. This year isn't *leap year* return result.

Judging leap year formula is

> (year % 4 = 0) AND (year  % 100 <> 0) OR (year % 400 = 0)

Addition this formula in `CASE WHEN` condition to make it

look like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_woy(timestamp with time zone) 
RETURNS int AS $$  
SELECT CASE WHEN (date_part('year',$1)::int % 4 = 0) AND ((date_part('year',$1)::int % 100 <> 0) OR (date_part('year',$1)::int % 400 = 0)) 
         THEN to_char($1, 'WW')::int -1 
       ELSE to_char($1, 'WW')::int
END
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

When you use your `f_woy` function, week of leap year will be same with week of normal year.

```
SELECT f_woy(('2007-06-24 14:19:46.502-07'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at 
time zone 'america/los_angeles')::date), 
       f_woy(('2008-06-24 14:19:46.502-07'::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' at 
time zone 'america/los_angeles')::date)
```

**Result**

```
f_woy   f_woy
25      25
```

sqlfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b43eb6f9c2accde5fc74ebe980a039d7

**EDIT**

*Leap Year* means that will add a Feb 29th in this year, So You can try this to make it.

`IsLeapYear` function gets this year is or isn't leap year.

```
create or replace function IsLeapYear(int)
returns boolean as $$
    select $1 % 4 = 0 and ($1 % 100 <> 0 or $1 % 400 = 0)
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

`f_woy` function gets current weeks number.

```
create or replace function f_woy(date)
returns int language plpgsql as $$
declare
    currentYear int = extract (year from $1);
    LeapYearShift int = 1 + (IsLeapYear(currentYear) and $1 > make_date(currentYear, 2, 28))::int;
begin
    return ((extract(doy from $1)::int)- LeapYearShift) / 7+ 1;
end;
$$;
```

**NOTE**

- `1 + (IsLeapYear(currentYear) and $1 > make_date(currentYear, 2, 28))::int` mean if this year is  *LeapYear* need to minus more one day(Feb 29th). let days  of *LeapYear* same with normal year.

[SQLFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=aee5198f6f2f5ee0ec1a193b7b0bfcf1)

Comment: That works for months after leap day (March and later), but Jan and Feb show different weeks of the year (offset by 1). I tried adding this conditional statement: (date_part('month',$1)::int > 2), and it works for Feb but didn't work for May 24.  Any thoughts? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c8b8a807a58007e8f4d28b3a386bd842

Comment: Thank you!!!  I marked it as working because for most practical purposes it is perfect.  However, i note that if I put Dec 31 in as a date, it shows as week 53 instead of week 52.  Any thoughts?